Fan speed dropping in turbo mode ROG Zephyrus M16 GU603HM
I'm using ghelper instead of armoury crate since it has been severely lagging my laptop recently (high in private byte according to process hacker). However I've been running into problem that fan speed dropping (5000 rpm) after running turbo mode for a while despite overheating (95C), causing severe lagging and frame rate dropping. Clicking on turbo again will tune up the speed for a while and drop back down eventually, as if it auto-switches to silence mode occasionally.
Ghelper said they don't control the fan speed, bios does. So I looked up for fan control method in bios. However many tutorial mentioned "Q-fan control", which is absent in my bios. Have no idea what to do next. Anything associated to where to find q fan control or straight up another method to solve fan problem will be appreciated.


Your system should not be overheating that’s a sign airflow is restricted. 4800 RPM should be more then adequate to cool your system and despite that your temperatures are higher than normal

@Ramhound The ghelper developer just post an [experimental build][1]  which have affect on the fan speed. Now it's running relatively normal and my cpu is 80 instead of 95 when running the same program. (tbf I doubt it's only 95 cuz it's literally burning my fingers on my keyboard)
[1]: https://github.com/seerge/g-helper/discussions/2272#discussioncomment-10784481

The experimental build on ghelper helped. Fan speed is relatively normal now but just a little more sensitive to temperature changes.

Your CPU is still going to overheat and throttle at those temperatures

idk but 70~80 is kinda normal for laptop, at least for what I've heard and since I first bought the laptop it's just being like this all the time.

Your system is running at 96C not 70C-80C Anything past 85C I would expect your system to throttle.

That's before the fan speed fix, after the fix it's 70~80
